# Is it possible to run Guild Wars 2 from a USB-connected drive?

Tags: guild-wars-2

My machine is an early 2011 17-inch MacBook Pro with a 2.2 Ghz Core i7, 4 GB RAM, and a Radeon HD 6750M with 1 GB of VRAM.

Based on the published [system reqs](https://en.support.guildwars2.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1119), I think it should be able to run the game client, at least at minimal settings. (Comments on that are welcome.)

However the internal HD doesn't have nearly enough free space.

I have an external USB drive with plenty of space though.

Could I install GW 2 on that and run it from there?

Comment: Well you can, it will be very slow though. Your machine is not very powerful to begin with, putting it on a USB HDD will make it even slower.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. You're probably right. I guess need to think about getting a new computer if I want to start messing around with MMOs :(

Comment: @Ethan And don't buy a mac ;)

Comment: Is it a USB 3.0? Guild Wars 1 manages to run from a USB surprisingly well, I might try with GW2 later today and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, @diverges. I would be curious to know if you do the experiment. I ordered a new internal drive with larger capacity today, as I kind of needed it anyway.

Comment: I think it might play quite well actually, since the game loads more elements in memory during play and the computer itself doesn't seem terrible for this game. However the loading screens between maps will give you a moment to get a cup of coffee most likely, as the loading screen preloads a lot of elements from disk.

Comment: @Bazzz - A USB 2.0 external drive is about 3-4x slower then a SATA III drive.

Comment: @Ramhound that sounds perfect for a cup of coffee! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I installed a larger solid state drive.

GW2 runs reasonably well on the machine described in my question.

Not the greatest -- you have to put it on pretty low settings -- but definitely playable.

Answer (score 0):

I just confirmed that **yes you can run Guild Wars 2 from an external drive**. I plugged in an external USB 3 HDD, moved the Guild Wars 2 file from the Applications folder to the external drive, double-clicked it, downloaded an update, logged on, and everything worked fine.

It is a little slower on a USB 3.0 external than an internal SSD, but freeing up 26 GB is worth it to me.

This is on a MacBook Pro using the Beta GW2 client with Heart of Thorns.